# How do I delete a user in Phabricator

Tags: phabricator

I have an installation of Phabricator and a user created a username in a non standard form. The user was deleted from the approval screen.

But now its impossible to recreate the user in the new form because case insensitively the username is the same, but the email address is also the same

How can I tell Phabricator to really delete the user and start again

Answer (score 7):

cd to the phabricator directory

```
./bin/remove destroy @username

Are you absolutely certain you want to destroy this object? [y/N] y
```

Sorry to answer my own question, but I couldn't easily find the answer on google, I guessed if its was in stack-overflow I'd be able to find it next time.